# What is the probability value for a test of hypothesis seeking to show the the department's claim is correct?

Tags: probability

North Carolina department of transportation claimed that at most, 18% of the passenger cars exceed the 70 miles per hour on interstate 40 between Raleigh and Durham. A random sample of 300 cars found 48 cars exceeding 70 miles per hour. What is the probability value for a test of hypothesis seeking to show the the department's claim is correct?

My doubt is, if we take Null as p=0.18 and Alternative as p<0.18, then both of these attest to the claim of Department, which is a probability of at most 0.18. Can we have something like, Null as p less than or equal to 0.18 and Alternative as p> 0.18, and if we can  reject alternative, then the department's claim can be verified as true?

I might be conceptually wrong. Please advise. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The null hypothesis is what is being assumed; that would be the claim that $p \le 0.18$. Normally we take the alternative to be the opposite, so in this case, $p \gt 0.18$. This way if we decide to reject the null hypothesis we reject the claim being made by the department. Otherwise we do not reject it (which is not the same as proving it's true by the way)